# Trigger Event Click upon page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I do not know why I can not trigger a click event on my controller upon page load. What I want is the checkboxed to be click literally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dean" ng-click="btnChange($event, values, 1)" id="one" name="one" class="here" >
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="armada" ng-click="btnChange($event, values, 2)" id="two" name="one" class="here" >
        <!--<p ng-repeat="btn in btns">-->
        <!--  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="btn.bool" class="here" > {{ btn.value }}-->
        <!--</p>-->
        {{btn  }}
        {{values  }}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('ngToggle', [])
            .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.btns = [{}, {}, {}];
            $scope.values = [];
            $scope.btnChange = function(event, model, val){
              _this = angular.element(event.target);
              x = _this.prop("checked");
              if(x){
                model.push(val);
              }else{
                index = model.indexOf(val);
                model.splice(index, 1);
              }
            };
            angular.element("#one").triggerHandler("click");
        }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7DpCvkKLlKhRc3YwFTq0?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you have used jQuery on the page. So you can simply do this :

```
 $(function(){
     angular.element("#one").trigger("click"); 
 });
```

A complete jQuery solution would be :

```
 $(function(){
    $("#one").click(); 
 });
```

A complete angular solution would be (like others mentioned) :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.element("#one").trigger("click"); 
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0OHDIVB2JGqDZnF56E6M?p=preview

You are triggering the code to click when the document is not completely ready/rendered so you need to wait till the entire document(or in this case, your checkbox) is loaded and only then you can perform actions on your elements.

Comment: THANKS A LOT! I might as well use this as this is much simpler and a hybrid of Jquery and AngularJS

Answer (score 2):

You can place it on controller like this

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.element("#one").trigger("click"); 

        });
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBCRO2qGDo5kfgP5OLO9?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a small timeout to trigger a click

```
$timeout(function() {
          angular.element('#one').click();
        }, 100);
```

I have updated your plunker link check it out [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3evMoqsVKCesLQhdOiU?p=preview)

Or  You can do

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          angular.element("#one").trigger("click"); 
        });
```